# How do I put my content in the right place and for all my pages?

Tags: php, html

I need help for something please. I'm working on my structure, but I've some problems...

I created a page called "page-container.php" and the content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?= $page_title; ?></title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/fonts/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body id="<?= $page_id; ?>">
        <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="page-content">
                <?php if(isset($sidebar)): ?>
                <div class="main-container">
                    <div class="main-content">
                <?php endif; ?>
                <h1 class="page-title"><?= $page_title; ?></h1>
                I WANT TO HAVE MY CONTENT HERE FOR ALL MY PAGES
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see the "I WANT TO HAVE MY CONTENT HERE FOR ALL MY PAGES".

What I mean is that when I write the content in my other pages (for example, my registration page), I want that all the content is placed at this location, like this:

http://prntscr.com/a3oz5k

All my other pages are like this (exemple with index.php):

```
<?php

$page_title = "Home";
$page_id = "home";

?>

<?php require "includes/page-container.php"; ?>
```

If I want to write some content in this page, I need to do like this:

```
<?php

$page_title = "Home";
$page_id = "home";

?>

<?php require "includes/page-container.php"; ?>

<div id="mycontent">
<p>Heellloo</p>
</div>
```

But look the result: http://prntscr.com/a3p32y

In the code source this is not normal... http://prntscr.com/a3p3kg

My content is below the html and body tag and I want it to be placed just below my h3 title. How can I do please?

Comment: make it two diff scirpts header.php and footer.php. Have tags uptill  `<h1>` in header and rest in footer.php.  add require header.php above your hello content and footer bellow you hello content

Answer (score 1):

Simple example using [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php).

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

<div id="mycontent">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>

<?php
$page = ob_get_clean();
require "includes/page-container.php";
?>
```

And then in `page-container.php` just do `echo $page;`.
Your code will be still formatted as HTML in your editor instead if it would be in a variable.

You can also split your `page-container.php` into two parts and include the first part before the content and the second one after.

Reference: [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), [ob_get_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Comment: Yes, I tried the two parts solution, but I have some problems, because I want to put a sidebar to my structure. There is not another solution with the $page variable and have all the content in?

Comment: You can do following:
`<?php
ob_start();
?>

<div id="sidebar">
<p>Sidebar</p>
</div>

<?php
$sidebar= ob_get_clean();
require "includes/page-container.php";
?>`

And then `echo $page` and `echo $sidebar` where you need in the template. You can have more variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep another vartiable say $page_content and use as below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?= $page_title; ?></title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/fonts/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body id="<?= $page_id; ?>">
    <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">

            <h1 class="page-title"><?= $page_title; ?></h1>
            <?= $page_content; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And for some content in another page

```
<?php

$page_title = "Home";
$page_id = "home";
$page_content  = "content";

?>

<?php require "includes/page-container.php"; ?>
```

`

Comment: Yes, but for the $page_content = "content". It's not good, because I need to use html, etc. in this. I don't want  to use a simple text.